# Google App Script bootstrap not working

Tags: google-apps-script

We have to work on Google App Script and we Used Bootstrap for Our Google apps Script for UI but from last day is 16-May-2017 it is not working.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for reporting sudden service disruptions.  A good question includes some code, an explanation of what you have tried, and error messages, if there are any.  You should post this in a different community:  [Link to Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 0):

This issue now resolved, following are the server side code useful.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Shivaji Test')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
}
```

add .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1') this tag

Thanks